# Is it possible to execute a javascript function from the java part of jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

In jsp , I want a function defined in javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function forSignup(){

    if(document.getElementById("sign").style.display=='none')
    {

        document.getElementById("sign").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("login form").style.display='none';
    }

    else
    {
        document.getElementById("login form").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("sign").style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

to be executed when called from the java part of jsp `<% %>` on a condition when a servlet sends a value of an integer as 1 .

Is it possible to do ?

if yes please tell me how should I perform it ?

Comment: JavaScript is a client side language, Java is a server side language.

Comment: @kevingreen Wrong on both counts.

Comment: @chrylis Care to elaborate, or contribute to the discussion?

Comment: @kevingreen Java can run client-side, and JavaScript is used server-side in both the JVM and Node.

Comment: @chrylis This obviously wasn't node.js, and JSP's aren't generally used in client(desktop) applications.

Comment: Just put an if around that condition. And then put a <script> tag in your document within that condition that calls the javascript function. You're only calling it conditionally client side based on that server side condition though. I assume that's what you're trying to do? See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is roughly what you're looking for. If a server side variable (intValue) is equal to 1, then call the function, otherwise do not.

```
<% if (intValue == 1) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        forSignup();
    </script>
<% } %>
```

Bear in mind though, that you're not actually calling this Javascript function "from Java". You are merely ensuring that the Javascript function is called based on the server side condition, dependent on the integer value in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<c:if>` block to include the JavaScript based on a variable in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can be executed from Java code, but it isn't simple, and the code you posted has to run from the DOM and thus *can't* be handled server-side. Moreover, using scriptlets is strongly discouraged; it's much better to prepare the model for a page (usually using a framework such as Spring MVC) and then use templates for rendering only.

What you're wanting to do is conditional logic, determining whether elements are displayed based on some state such as whether the user is logged in. Use `<c:if>` to selectively include code in the rendered HTML (and just set CSS directly instead of taking a detour through JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute java code in javascript method

```
<script >
 function login(){
 <% System.out.println("Hiiiiiiiii"); 

 %>
 var password="test"
 }
</script>
```